# How to play internet radio stations in the Music app on iOS 13?

Tags: music.app, ios

I read several posts, that it should be possible to listen to internet radio stations from TuneIn in Apple Music (e.g. https://www.audioxpress.com/news/tunein-and-apple-bring-the-world-s-radio-stations-to-apple-music-and-all-siri-enabled-devices). But It does not work for me - neither Siri (language: German) nor typed search for radio stations yields any result.

My question: how can I listen to internet radio stations (e.g. [hr3](https://www.hr3.de/index.html), [srf3](https://www.srf.ch/radio-srf-3), ...) using Music on iOS 13? I have an Apple Music subscription.

If it is relevant: I am in Switzerland.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it has something to do with your location. I'm in the USA and when I searched for "hr3" in the Music app it immediately showed that station you are looking for as a result. Maybe TuneIn only works with the Apple Music app in some countries?

Comment: That is my guess as well - on the one side good to hear that it works in the US, on the other side, bad that it does not work anywhere. Strange. Any further info to this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's still possible, but at the time, I was retrieving the streaming URL, I going to  iTunes > file menu and opening a link (or something of that style). Once the link played on iTunes, I had a playlist named radio, I added it to the playlist and synchronized the playlist with the iPhone. If iTunes could read the streaming format the iPhone too. I don't remember the formats he didn't support, but there are very few for me. To be sure that your url contains only the streaming URL you test it on a browser, because I already had url that looked like the stream, but it was not the case. If you just have a player it's good, it's the stream URL. If you have a web page, you must continue your research.  I would get the url in the source code of the pages ...

Comment: iTunes does not exist anymore in Catalena, and I don't think there is any way of pasting an URL into the Music app (iOS 13 or Catalena) - please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can still add stream urls to music (In the file menu you have open a stream url or cmd+u), but it is no longer possible to pass them to the iphone as before. Probably due to radio.... Another solution is to bookmark strem urls in Safaris and play them in safari. The volume works and so does the play/pause. I tested with color 3 and it' s working fine.

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I would like to have it in music is automation with a AirPlay speaker. Manually, I have a good way of playing them.

Answer (score 1):

Tell Siri to play it. E.G. there is a radio station here called 101.1 ESPN. I tell Siri to play 101.1 espn and it usually works minus content restriction bs.

Comment: Yup - see the answer from MacMost.